# Postresql Updating a Table with Subquery from another table

Tags: postgresql

I am working in postgressql and am trying to update a credential_flag column in table1 with a subquery on credential_type in table2. My subquery works, but I can't get table 1 to update correctly. Both tables have a user_id field for the join. I'm getting a "syntax error at or near join" with my current code:

```
UPDATE table1
SET credential_flag =
  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.user_id)
  CASE
  WHEN t2.credential_type LIKE 'AA/AS Degree%' THEN 1
  WHEN t2.credential_type LIKE 'Occupational Skills%' THEN 1
  ELSE 0 
  END 
  FROM t2)
JOIN table1 ON table1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `UPDATE FROM` syntax. [From the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> ```
> UPDATE accounts SET contact_first_name = first_name,
>                     contact_last_name = last_name
>   FROM salesmen WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id;
> ```

In your case, this turns out like so

```
UPDATE table1
SET credential_flag = (
  CASE
  WHEN t2.credential_type LIKE 'AA/AS Degree%' THEN 1
  WHEN t2.credential_type LIKE 'Occupational Skills%' THEN 1
  ELSE 0 
  END 
)
FROM t2
WHERE table1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```